# How to create multiple objects at once and ignoring unique constraint exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is an array of hash for creating `ApplicationRecord` objects.

```
a = [{name: 'foo', title: 'bar'},
     {name: 'foo2', title: 'bar2'}]
```

I can create multiple objects by `Foo.create(a)` and I can use `rescue` clause to catch the unique constraint exception.

But I couldn't find out how to create multiple objects at once ignoring the exceptions.

I could write it only by using loop.

```
a.each do |hash|
  begin
    Foo.create(hash)
  rescue
    next
  end
end
```

or

```
a.each do |hash|
   Foo.find_or_created_by(name: hash[:name], title: hash[:title])
end
```

How can I create objects at once in situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
# not Foo.create!(a)
Foo.create(a)
```

?, it could takes array of hashes as params, and saves the ones passed the validation, ignores the ones does't.

By the way, I dont think

```
Foo.create(hash)
```

will raise any validation exceptions, since it not the '!' version(like: Foo.create!(hash)). And if the unique constraint exception from database, not validation, then you need a validation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    a.each{|hash| Foo.create(hash) }
  end
  #handle success here
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
   #handle failure here
end
```

An exception looks like

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Title can't be blank>
```

And
exception.message

```
# => "Validation failed: Email can't be blank"
```

Hope this can help. :)